# How to test deserialization in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

What's the right way to write a unit test for deserializing a JSON object in Web API?

In my application I noticed from looking at the trace information that Web API is trying to deserialize an object parameter which comes from the request body by calling JsonMeadiaTypeFormatter.ReadFromAsync.  I'm trying to isolate the problem so I wrote these test. ReadTestItem fails.  The other example ReadInt passes, so it seems like I'm on the right track but I'm not sure if this is what Web API is really doing.

**EDIT: code fixed and FormatterConfig added**

```
class TestClass
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class FormatterTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReadTestItem()
    {
        MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection();
        FormatterConfig.RegisterGlobalFormatters(formatters);

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = formatters[0] as JsonMediaTypeFormatter;
        Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString("{ type: \"Equal\", value: \"1\" }");
        var content = new StreamContent(s);
        var logger = new Mock<IFormatterLogger>().Object;

        var task = formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(TestClass), s, content, logger);
        TestClass result = task.Result as TestClass;
        Assert.AreEqual("Equal", result.Type);
        Assert.AreEqual("1", result.Value);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestReadInt()
    {
        MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection();
        FormatterConfig.RegisterGlobalFormatters(formatters);

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = formatters[0] as JsonMediaTypeFormatter;
        Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString("2");
        var content = new StreamContent(s);
        var logger = new Mock<IFormatterLogger>().Object;

        var task = formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(int), s, content, logger);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, task.Result);
    }

    public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Here's the formatter configuration:

```
public class FormatterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFormatters(MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters)
    {
        var jsonSerializerSettings = formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

        // serialize every enum as a string
        jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());

        // include null value fields
        jsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        // use camel case
        jsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // indented formatting
        bool indent;
        Boolean.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dex.indentjson"], out indent);
        formatters.JsonFormatter.Indent = indent;

        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the test `ReadTestItem` fail?  Also, can you share the definition of `FilterItemDTO`?

Comment: That was my mistake it should have been TestClass instead of FilterItemDTO.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach looks fine to me. You're correct in noticing that ReadFromStreamAsync gets called on the request body. Now there's two strange things going on:

- The type you pass in to the first test is FilterItemDTO. But then you expect the result to be a TestClass? Whatever type you pass in to the formatter is the type you should expect to have deserialized. Were you intending to pass in TestClass to ReadFromStreamAsync instead?
- TestClass has members Type and Value, so Json.NET will expect members "Type" and "Value in the JSON, not "type" and "value". The casing matters. But there is an easy way to get camel casing with this line of code:

  ```
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
  ```

Comment: Yes you're right I wrote FilterItemDTO instead of TestClass.  I fixed the code in the question so the tests pass now.  Also I am using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver, I added the code for the FormatterConfig class.  Thanks for your help!